# Clang and C++11 headers

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, mingw, clang

I'm trying to get Clang to work on Windows, to eventually develop with Qt Creator to see if it's a viable alternative to Visual Studio.

I got LLVM and Clang 3.2 (SVN Revision 163238) to compile using [MinGW w64](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Automated%20Builds/) (mingw-w64-bin_i686-mingw_20111220.zip) and also pointed to gcc's C++ header directories by adding `AddMinGWCPlusPlusIncludePaths("D:/Code/mingw/lib/gcc", "x86_64-w64-mingw32", "4.7.0");` to `clang/lib/Frontend/InitHeaderSearch.cpp`, although I think that might not be the most up-to-date method. Anyway, Clang seems to find most of those headers.

However, when compiling a simple Hello World:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::cout << "test\n";
  return 0;
}
```

using `clang++ main.cpp` I get this error:

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:
In file included from D:/Code/mingw/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-ming32/4.7.0./include/c++\iostream:39:
In file included from D:/Code/mingw/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-ming32/4.7.0./include/c++\ostream:39:
In file included from D:/Code/mingw/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-ming32/4.7.0./include/c++\ios:39:
In file included from D:/Code/mingw/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-ming32/4.7.0./include/c++\iosfwd:41:
In file included from D:/Code/mingw/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-ming32/4.7.0./include/c++\postypes.h:41:
D:/Code/mingw/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-ming32/4.7.0./include/c++\cwchar:45:10: fatal error:
      'wchar.h' file not found
```

So, Clang apparently finds several C++ headers including `iostream` but fails to find `wchar.h`. Turns out that `wchar.h` is located in `.../include/c++\tr1` where Clang doesn't look for it. Moving those TR1 headers up one directory doesn't help either.

What did I do wrong here? Is the gcc C++ library not compatible with Clang, since apparently it still hasn't integrated some TR1 libraries into the standard? Where could I get a compatible C++11 library for Clang (for Windows!)?

Comment: `wchar.h` should come from your C library. It doesn't necessarily need to be shipped with Clang.

Comment: I've tried long to work clang on windows but it seems a no way...for now you cab use mingw (4.7.2) or vc++2012 express

Comment: you can tryi to build qt 5 with mingw-64-4.7.2, look at http://qt-project.org/wiki/MinGW-64-bit

Comment: Please share your invocation command line. Did you remember to pass -ID:\Code\mingw\include to clang++ ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882753/clang-on-windows

Comment: Have you tried using `libc++`? If you are building from source, it shouldn't be much more trouble to bake `libc++` into the mix.

Comment: I assume you've got CONFIG += c++11 in your .pro?

Comment: There is a nice question here http://stackoverflow.com/q/8882753/1065190 which discusses how to use Clang on Windows. The answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8883505/1065190

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misconfigured/mispatched Clang. You need to also add MinGW-w64 paths, somewhere around where you added your version.

Use the prebuilt version I provide with explanation here:
[Clang on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882753/clang-on-windows/8883505#8883505)

I modified Clang to work with the MinGW-w64 headers and GCC 4.6.3 libstdc++ headers and libraries. Currently, it's stuck at version 3.2, but if you apply a similar patch to the sources (of which I unfortunately do not have a patch file) you should be able to use it as well.

The one I provide is just extract, add to PATH, and use. And 32-bit only.

Also note you are using an ancient version of MinGW-w64 GCC, and you should really update that.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the "wchar.h" manually and placing it in your local working directory of your visual studio project. Works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass `-nostdinc++` to clang you should be able to point it to the exact configuration of includes with multiple `-I` switches. Try `-nostdsysteminc -nobuiltininc` as well.

And `-v` should show you where and in what order it looks for headers when it compiles:

```
clang++ -v -nostdinc++ -ID:/Code/mingw/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-ming32/4.7.0./include/c++ -ID:/Code/mingw/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-ming32/4.7.0./include/c++/tr1 foo.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem using Clang --version 3.4 (198054) and mingw-get.exe --version 0.6.2-beta-20131004-1: it turned out I had installed MinGW incorrectly: I had initially only checked the box for 'mingw-gcc-g++' in the mingw-get.exe package selection dialog, adding 'mingw32-base' later on solved this wchar_t.h problem: clang++.exe -std=c++11 compiled C++11 iostream code just fine.